# How to pipe() npm-request only if HTTP 200 is received?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-request, node-streams

I have the following code:

```
let request = require('request');
let fs = require('fs');

request.get('http://localhost:8080/report.rtf')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/savedDoc.rtf'));
```

It works well, but only if the document is successfully downloaded from the given URL. However, if there is any HTTP: 403, 404 or any other error, an empty file is saved with zero length!

How can I `.pipe()` this only in case of HTTP: 200 response without using any additional HEAD requests? It should be possible to do in one go!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check `.statusCode` before piping:

```
const req = request
  .get('http://localhost:8080/report.rtf')
  .on('response', function (res) {
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
      req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/savedDoc.rtf'))
    }
  })
```

Comment: How come this doesn't work?
`const req = request.get('http://thewalter.net/stef/software/rtfx/sample.rtf', (error, response, body) => {
  if(response.statusCode === 200) {
    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/testDoc.rtf'));
  }
});`

Comment: no errors, but if the response is 200 then the file that is saved is empty

Comment: I guess the request stream gets closed by the time this `(err,res,body) => {}` handler is executed

Comment: Probably yep. Is the `body` a `Buffer` with the response?